# Rig's bone still moves/animates to different location on next frame even when keyframe is deleted

Tags: animation, armature, bones, nla-editor

I'm not sure what is happening. I've deleted multiple tracks from NLA editor as well. There are no other keyframes when I reset this bone (Alt + G) yet when I move to next frame it stretches back out like this. I've Deleted all the actions and unhid all bones. I'm using blender 3.5.1. I've used animation layers addon as well but not sure that is the issue here.[image]

[image: After hitting alt + G]

[image: After moving one frame forward]

Comment: pls provide blend file. How shall we know what you did?

Comment: For sure. I'll upload it to google drive.

Comment: Blend file here:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qj5GPOwE19S1mFjL4gM6N6ekxq23bLwC/view?usp=sharing